# Steps do I have to take to make IISExpress to run the iisnode when IISExpress is run from Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, iis-express, iisnode

Here are the technologies used in my work environment:

-Node JS version 8.10.0 win x64

-Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3

-iisnode v0.22.1 x64

-IIS Express

When I installed iisnode, the iisnode configuration was located here:

C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\configuration\web.config

Within C:\Program Files\iisnode\www , there are directories ( one directory for each node application )

I created an ASP.NET MVC solution in Visual Studio.

Now when I run the aforementioned ASP.NET MVC solution in Visual Studio, the IISExpress will properly deploy and run the solution.

However, how can I configure IISExpress to run the iisnode that was installed?  What steps do I have to take to make IISExpress to run the iisnode when IISExpress is run from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode) says

> **Installing for IIS 7.x/8.x**
>
> ```
> * Install iisnode for IIS 7.x/8.x: x86 or x64 - choose bitness matching your system
> * To set up samples, from the administrative command prompt call %programfiles%\iisnode\setupsamples.bat
> * Go to http://localhost/node
> ```
>
> **Installing for IIS Express/WebMatrix**
>
> ```
> * Install WebMatrix using the Web Platform Installer
> * Open WebMatrix, choose “Site from folder”, enter %localappdata%\iisnode\www, start the site, and play with the iisnode
> ```
>
> samples, or
>       * Use node.js templates to get started quickly with an Express application or a skeleton Hello World

But WebMatrix is already end of life. So you need to manually create a site on IIS Express instead (or use a tool like [Jexus Manager](http://jexusmanager.com)).

There does not seem to be any Visual Studio integration mentioned though.